# Ajax call on Save in Django Admin

Tags: django, ajax, django-admin

How to call Ajax on save and continue in the Django admin model?

Any hack or third party for calling ajax on saving the model with all type of fields in Django admin?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried.

Comment: Currently in DJango 1.11, whenever we save record, at that time validation is checked on page refresh.

I want to validate django admin form by ajax.